# How do I view syslogs on a remote server with Windows and a web browser?

Tags: syslog

I have Ubuntu Clients running 12.04 LTS and a Ubuntu machine as the server. Now I have configured Ubuntu machines as syslog clients and they are intended to send their logs to the Ubuntu machine.

But how can I view those logs in my Windows machine? A browser-based solution is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [LogAnalyzer](http://loganalyzer.adiscon.com/), a PHP frontend for rsyslog in conjunction with Ubuntu. It does lag if the volume of records gets to be too much though.